# Scaling jQuery function without duplicating code

Tags: jquery, html

The script below is used to hide a paragraph until all text fields inside div.form have been filled out.

As it is now, in order to reveal the paragraphs I would have to fill out BOTH forms. What I want is for each form to act independently. In other words, if you filled out the three inputs in the first form, the paragraph in that first DIV would be revealed.

I can accomplish this by duplicating the code and adding more classes, but that is obviously less than ideal.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form one">  
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <p style="display:none">All inputs in this DIV contain text</p> 
</div>

<div class="form two">  
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <p style="display:none">All inputs in this DIV contain text</p> 
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.form input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('.form p').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.form p').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply select the `input`s and the `p` from that `.form`:

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false,
        $form = $(this).parent();

    $form.find('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
            return false; // stops the loop
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGBGK/

P.S. You could further optimize this by caching the selectors.

---

Alternatively, you could forego the loop, and just use an attribute selector:

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {

    var $form = $(this).parent(),
        empty = $form.find('input[value=]').length;

    if (empty) {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGBGK/1/

---

You can further shorten this, by using a ternary operator:

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {

    var $form = $(this).parent(),
        empty = $form.find('input[value=]').length;

    $form.find('p').css('display', empty ? 'none' : 'block');
});
```

...and finally, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGBGK/2/

Thanks @JesseB.

Comment: Actually, returning false won't stop the loop as far as I know. This is because it's a callback that is being triggered so the return type isn't important.

Comment: @JohnP - From the docs: `We can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false.` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Ah nice! I didn't know that you could do that. Thanks for the ref

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false, $form = $(this).closest('.form');
    $form.find('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $form.find('p').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Note that this is still very inefficient in terms of rerunning the same selections continuously; you might want to

- cache the results of the $form.find() calls using $.data or some other approach.
- iterate over the inputs, rather than using $.each(), so that you can break as soon as you find an empty one (it saves checking all the rest).  Iteration is also more efficient than $.each() anyway.

Comment: I think `$(this).closest('form');` should be `$(this).closest('.form');`. It's a class selector.

Comment: Good point.  Your answer is much more thorough anyway, so I've upvoted it instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are already several other answers but I'll add the one I just wrote up.  I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYmgz/) for it also.

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {
    // get and store the current form we're inside of
    var thisform = $(this).parents('.form'),
        empty = false;

    // keep track of whether the form has been filled out or not
    $('input', thisform).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            empty = true;
            return true;
        }
    });

    // set the display of this forms p tag element depending on whether
    // the form has been filled out or not
    $('p', thisform).css('display', (empty ? 'none' : 'block'));
});
```

### Update

And just because I did, here's the js if you wanted to use something other than jQuery's each:

```
$('.form input').keyup(function() {
    // get and store the current form we're inside of
    var thisform = $(this).parents('.form');

    // keep track of whether the form has been filled out or not
    var empty = $('input[value=]', thisform).length;

    // set the display of this forms p tag element depending on whether
    // the form has been filled out or not
    $('p', thisform).css('display', (empty ? 'none' : 'block'));
});
```

Comment: You can simplify that to just `var empty = $('input[value=]', thisform).length;`. If all `input`s have any text in them, the length will be 0. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGBGK/1/ . However, don't forget: just because it looks shorter does not actually mean that it's faster...

Comment: @JosephSilber I updated it with your simplification.  Nice one!